# How can i access to my elements in my JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse an get value of my elements in my JSON.

```
import json
  
f = open('links.json',)
  
data = json.load(f)
  
for i in data['jsonObject']['links']:
    for y in data['jsonObject']['coordonates']:
        if (i['take1'] == y):
          point1 = y
        if (i['take2'] == y):
            point2 = y
    print(point1['x'])
    print(point1['y'])
    print(point2['x'])
    print(point2['y'])


f.close()
```

And my json is like this

```
{
    "jsonObject": {
        "coordonates": {
            "id1": {
                "x": 100,
                "y": 60
            },
            "id2": {
                "x": 50,
                "y": 100
            },
            "id3": {
                "x": -100,
                "y": 20
            },
            "id4": {
                "x": 30,
                "y": 10
            },
        },
        "links": [
            {
                "take1": "id4",
                "take2": "id1",
            },
            {
                "take1": "id4",
                "take2": "id3",
            },
            {
                "take1": "id3",
                "take2": "id2",
            },
            {
                "take1": "id2",
                "take2": "id1",
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

With my code, i want to go to "links", get the two ids. When i have my two id, i'm going to "coordonates". And now i want to get the "x" and "y" of the two id.
But my problem is when i'm trying to access to the 'x' and 'y' i have

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And when i'm printing `print(y['x'])`, i have the same problem. I can't access to the y elements.

Anyone have an idea of my mistake ? And how can i do to get my 'x' and 'y' ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is only the key, not the content. But you already have a dictionary, to access the ids, so the inner for-loop is not necessary.

```
with open('links.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

coordinates = data['jsonObject']['coordonates']
for link in data['jsonObject']['links']:
    point1 = coordinates[link['take1']]
    point2 = coordinates[link['take2']]
    print(point1['x'])
    print(point1['y'])
    print(point2['x'])
    print(point2['y'])
```